# Пустая FormData при отправке AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Отправляю файл через AJAX (фотографию). Проверяю содержимое объектов в console.log() и вижу следующее: (это файл, который мне нужно загрузить)

[image: Сам файл, который нужно загрузить]

После того, как я преобразую его в FormData:

```
  function createFormData(images) { // передаю файл(массив файлов)

                var formImage = new FormData();

                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

                    formImage.append(i, images[i]); 
                }
                console.log(formImage); 
                uploadFormData(formImage);   //Функция загрузки AJAX            
            }
```

В консоли видно следующее: 
[image: Пустая FormData]

[image: FormData]

То есть, FormData пустая. Правильно понимаю?

При передаче FormData AJAXом, сервер ничего не принимает.

Comment: Он показал объект нажмите на него он откроется.

Comment: Добавил картинку. FormData пустая

Comment: Попробуйте запринтить вызов функций `keys()` & `values()`

Comment: Думаю вы не попадаете в цикл, проверяйте images